# Symfony 2.0 route parameters _format

Tags: routes, symfony, format

i have routing:

```
user:
    pattern:  /.{_format}
    defaults: { _controller: AlefUserBundle:User:index, _format: json }
    requirements: { _format: (xml|json|php), _method: GET }
```

And of course it works in browser. But when i try to create menu with `KnpMenuBundle` i get only `/user/` as link:

```
$menu->addChild('Użytkownicy', array('route' => 'user',
    'routeParameters' => array('_format' => 'json'),
        'attributes' => array(
            'title' => 'Lista użytkowników',
            'data-icon' => 'user',
            'data-id' => 'user_list',
        )
    ));
```

I tried clearing cache but it simply does not work. Is there a way to archive this? Or i need to type Uri?

Answer (score 3):

Well i changed it to `{format}`. It works almost as intended:

```
user:
    pattern:  /list.{format}
    defaults: { _controller: AlefUserBundle:User:index, format: html }
    requirements: { _format: (xml|json|html), format: (xml|json|html), _method: GET }
```

But i also added 1 line to controller:

```
public function indexAction($format) //$_format
{
    $this->getRequest()->setRequestFormat($format);
...
}
```

And it works...